# Using AWS services, How do I parallel process a set of documents in a single unit of work, and fail if any 1 of the documents fails to be processed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, microservices, aws-step-functions, orchestration

I have a set of 10 documents, and I want to process the 10 documents in parallel in a way such that if any 1 of the 10 documents fails to be processed, the unit of work fails itself.

Suppose for example that I have a collection of document URLs that are publicly accessible. I want to download each file in the collection to perhaps S3, run something like OCR on each document, and somehow when all 10 documents have been OCR'd, update some database flag to persist that the entire unit of work (OCR 10 documents in this case) is complete.

What options are available to accomplish this in AWS?

It appears to be like step functions might be one approach. How else might I accomplish this unit of work in a transactional way?

Again, I am starting with an input of an array/collection of public URLs, and I want to bring all those images into the AWS space, process those documents, and then mark a transaction as complete somehow (or fail the operation if any 1 of the documents fail).

I might like to retry doing the download from the public URL to perhaps S3 some configured number of times before declaring that the entire unit of work has failed. But, if any 1 of the 10 documents fails to be imported into AWS, fail the entire batch.

What are my options? Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box AWS service that would do this for you. The **continue/fail logic** would need to be coded in whatever system you are writing to perform the work.

You are correct that **AWS Step Functions** has the ability to run tasks in parallel, then take the output of those parallel paths and combine the information to make a decision (eg did they all succeed). The flow could then make a decision to accept all jobs or fail all jobs, but you would be responsible for writing the logic in Lambda functions that perform these actions.

See: [New – Step Functions Support for Dynamic Parallelism | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-step-functions-support-for-dynamic-parallelism/)